# Find first shared parentnode, it works but can it be done more Swift-y?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

The code does what I want it to do now, so I am asking this purely for learning something. Because I keep wondering if there's a more functional or Swift-y way to do it.

The goal is to figure out if `UIView` `oneView` is the parent of or a child of `UIView` `anotherView`, or that they shared a common ancestor. One thing I don't like is that I use `var views: [UIView] = [view]`, isn't there a way to condense it to a list directly without initializing a `var`? Or any other improvements I might have missed?

```
private static func determineSharedNode(between oneView: UIView, and anotherView: UIView) throws -> UIView {
    let oneViewStack = viewHierarchy(for: oneView)
    let anotherViewStack = viewHierarchy(for: anotherView)
    let sharedViews = oneViewStack.filter(anotherViewStack.contains)

    guard let firstSharedView = sharedViews.first else {
        throw ParentChildError.doNotShareNode
    }

    return firstSharedView
}

private static func viewHierarchy(for view: UIView) -> [UIView] {
    var views: [UIView] = [view]

    if let superview = view.superview {
        views.append(contentsOf: viewHierarchy(for: superview))
    }

    return views
}
```

Comment: Code reviews can be posted at https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to condense it down to the following:

```
func viewHierarchy(for view: UIView) -> [UIView] {
    return [view] + (view.superview.map(viewHierarchy) ?? [])
}
```

I think it's a lot better without intermediate `var`

Edited it a bit more so I got rid of the anonymous `$0`